# apt-get install -y doesn't work with license agreements, how to automate that?

Tags: ubuntu

For most packages that require a yes/no answer, this works fine for me:

```
sudo apt-get install -y ....
```

But if you require a package that makes you accept a license, how do you automatically agree to that?

For example, sun java:

```
sudo apt-get install -y sun-java6-bin sun-java6-jdk sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin
```

This requires me to select OK, and then yes.

Comment: Just some info: the sun flavored java has just been removed from debian. So you are running an unsupported program and you will not get security updates. (This also applies to ubuntu because of license restrictions). http://sylvestre.ledru.info/blog/sylvestre/2011/08/26/sun_java6_packages_removed_from_debian_u You should take a look at openjdk.

Answer (score 6):

There are some ways to do this:

1. Pre-answer with `debconf` by executing the following command before
   installing:

   ```
   echo sun-java6-jdk shared/accepted-sun-dlj-v1-1 select true | \
       /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections
   ```
2. Use `expect`:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/expect -f
   sudo apt-get -y install sun-java6-jre
   expect "[y/n]"
   sleep 1
   send -- "yes\r"
   ```

Comment: so would you put that echo line after the apt-get install line?

Answer (score 0):

For any package, you can use

```
apt-get -y install <package> << 'EOF'
ok
EOF
```

if in case you have multiple steps like

```
 1. Ok in step 1
 2. Enter Option 1/2
 3. y/n

    apt-get -y install <package> << 'EOF'
    ok
    1
    y
    EOF
```